# C++ Troubles with bot (MY private server)

Tags: c++, bots

I am making a server for a mmorpg somewhat soon, and I want to release a bot to go with it, since I don't want people having the ability to level to the maximum within a week or less but I don't want them to be discouraged from the amount of farming exp and items, so I want to make a bot that handles 1-8 accounts. I'm somewhat good with c++, do not tell me "use autoit" I am trying to make it look somewhat professional and actually work with the settings on their computer, I am good with the functions for windows.h but I can't figure out how to make the bot read or write to memory nor can I figure out how to use softice (not sure if I even have the correct one).

Now, the game is simple and I would have only 2 spells per account being used (long or short ranged) and monster icons and hp are always in the same x,y pos so the AI is very basic having all the accounts do the exact same things, but I can't figure out how to look at let alone edit the packets to allow my bot to work without having each account become the focus window at every step of the fight.

the reason for 1-8 accounts is that most people on the normal server have anywhere from 1-8 usually 4-8 once they reach higher levels to allow for them to be able to do things without searching for a group since most dungeons take up to 5 hours at higher levels and it would be easier to have all you need instead of being stuck half way through once someone decides that they have to get off or you need to leave.. you know how it can be. anyway,

it is strictly for my server, but its not up yet so I can't learn with it, and I'm not the host I am paying my friend to set it up but he has no idea how to make a bot so I'm looking for some help. 
I would like help with
-some tutorials on or around the subject.
or
-someone to help me through it (I don't need much help, an hour or two would probably be enough for me to get in the right direction)
or
-the source code to someones bot (I could probably look through it to find what I need.)
or
-where to go to find someone to teach me (cheap)

Now Please don't post things like "you shouldn't cheat" I am making this for a server I am supplying, so its not cheating since I allow it and give people the program for free on my website. And if you say something like "you'll have to practice with it on the real server", Yes I will, but I would be using level 1 accounts in the "noob" area in a place nobody ever goes (plus on the real server the noob area has individual 200 people servers so even if I go on it I wouldn't disturb anyone) and I am only using it for practice and then I would edit it once my server was up, so I am not cheating to get farther in the game or anything, it is purely for the use in my server. I also ask that people take this somewhat seriously, I am fairly good with C++ I am just stuck since I can't find where to teach myself this.

Also, admins please don't shut this down I realize that this could be taken as I am violating the terms of service but if you read this, I am not. Since it is for own MY server and I am not using it to cheat, I have a viable reason for making this and I do really need help.

**EDIT:**

I found some information that said I need to learn about sockets and networking in C++. I have located some tutorials for networking, but I would greatly appreciate something on sockets (all I have found are useless tidbits of information).

Comment: Did you write the client as well?  Seems if you did that it would be easier to add hooks and such  for a client-side aid.  You might also consider using server-side bots, similar to the mercenaries in Everquest.  They would most likely be more flexible, easier to implement, and could save you a bit of bandwidth if that's important.

Comment: I didn't write the client, my friend is setting everything up, my only job is money, the bot, and the website. 
I am a beginner to bots, so i am not sure what Hooks or server-side bot are sorry.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it would be way easier if the bot was a game-client itself. This way it could do everything a client could without hooking anything. The bot doesn't even need a useinterface, it could just run in the background. If this is possible depends on how modular your code is. In an ideal situation you could make a new application, referencing the game-client dll with the gamelogic and recieve requests from the server and send actions as a player would do.
Creating a bot that clicks on a client windows button is possible but complicated. But to help you with your request we need more info about how the client and server work. What languages are they written in, what APIs and Libraries are you using?
If you have no idea how to achieve this it and got no idea how the client works it would probably better for your friend to write the bot.